# Win32 API Serial Port -- how to get available number of bytes asynchronously?

Tags: c++, winapi, asynchronous

Windows 7, x64, C++, MSVC 2015 Community.

I'm writing a program which needs to identify the first serial port with activity on it.  Ideally I'd like not to lose the first byte that comes in.  There are four approaches I can think of:

1. Open all serial ports, for each one do an overlapped `ReadFile` of one byte, then a single `WaitForMulipleEvents`.  When that returns, close the non-active ports, and store the received byte someplace, and wrap subsequent `ReadFile`s in some function that knows to insert that first byte when needed.

   Pros: asynchronous, no polling, already mostly implemented.
   Cons:  Keeping track of an extra byte and wrapping `ReadFile` is annoying.
2. Basically #1, but find some way of shoving the byte back into the front of the serial driver buffer.  I've googled for days on this and haven't found anything.  Doesn't seem likely, but if it worked would prevent me from having to keep track of the extra byte.
3. Open all serial ports and poll for bytes available using `ClearCommError`.
   When something has bytes available, close the other ports.  Would need to add a delay in the loop so it doesn't bog the system down.  I don't want to see 100% CPU utilization when literally doing nothing but waiting for something to come in.

   Pros: Keeps subsequent `Readfile`s pure without having to wrap it and track an extra byte.
   Cons: Polling sucks when it seems there ought to be asynchronous methods available.  I'd have to tune the delay between polls to ensure I don't overflow when it's coming in potentially at up to 460kbps.
4. Find some way of using an overlapped `DeviceIoControl` call, followed by `WaitForMultipleEvents` to signal when bytes are available, but I haven't found any `IOCTL...` codes to do this.

The more I think about it, #3 sounds like the best option.  I don't like polling, but it avoids having to keep track of an extra byte.

Is there a clean asynchronous way to do what I need?
Can I/O completion ports come into play?

thanks

Comment: In C++ you already should use a SerialPort class. Method 1 may be implemented without storing bytes somewhere because no one will directly use ReadFile directly...

Comment: Well yeah.  I'm actually putting all this in a serial port class already, and the ReadFile stuff is already hidden behind some class methods.  So it's not the end of the world to just keep that byte around.

Comment: (1) seems quite simple and it's clearly correct. Usually, the best way to read streams is to always have one read IO outstanding. You can then insert data into a queue.

Comment: Hard to see why you would have to lose anything when you use ReadFile(), that buffer you need can be useful later.  But you can also simply use WaitCommEvent() to wait for EV_RXCHAR.

Comment: WaitCommEvent appears to be what I was looking for.  I'll check into this.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes that totally worked :)